# MySQL Joins Between Databases On Different Servers Using Python?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Database A resides on server server1, while database B resides on server server2.

Both servers {A, B} are physically close to each other, but are on different machines and have different connection parameters (different username, different password etc).

In such a case, is it possible to perform a join between a table that is in database A, to a table that is in database B?

If so, how do I go about it, programatically,

Answer (score 0):

Without doing something like replicating database A onto the same server as database B and then doing the JOIN, this would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, so I'm going to assume that when you do a query it comes back to python as an array of rows.

You could query table A and after applying whatever filters you can, return that result to the application. Same to table B. Create a 3rd Array, loop through A, and if there is a joining row in B, add that joined row to the 3rd array. In the end the 3rd array would have the equivalent of a join of the two tables. It's not going to be very efficient, but might work okay for small recordsets.